# How do I add a mute button to a video in HTML5?

Tags: html, button, video, html5-video, mute

Here is the [link](https://www.mpae.rocks/).

The video plays with its sound & etc. I want to add the mute button so people can actually pause it. Thanks in advance.

---

Source code:

```
<section id="video">
  <div class="header-container">
    <div class="video-container">
      <button id="mute-video">Toggle Mute</button>
      <video preload ="true" autoplay ="autoplay" loop volume="0">
        <source src ="video/MPAE_video.mp4" type="video/mp4">
      </video>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Please add the relevant code you are using for generating the output / the player. And show, what you have already tried for solving the problem.

Answer (score 1):

When you use video and source tag, it'll add basic control by itself like mute, play and pause. just add **controls** inside video tag.

[check this](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_video.asp)

```
<video width="640" controls><source src="video/MPAE_video.mp4"></source></video>
```